# JQuery AJAX method executes both "success" and "failure"

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX method to tell the user whether or not an email is available when registering.

```
$('#mainArea_txtEmail').keyup(function (e) {
    var inputemail = $(this).val();
    if (inputemail.length > 5)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/isEmailAvailable",
            data: '{email: "' + inputemail + '" }', 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: alert("available"),
            failure: alert("unavailable")
        });
    }
});
```

When a user types in an email, whether it is available or not, the browser displays the success alert and then the failure alert every time.

Here is the C# method:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string isEmailAvailable(string email)
    {
        BasePage page = new BasePage();
        string returnvalue;
        if (page.db.UserGet(email) == null)
        {
            returnvalue = "true";
        }
        else
        {
            returnvalue = "false";
        }
        return returnvalue;
    }
```

The `db.UserGet` method will try and find a database record of a user with the email address matching the `email` parameter. If there is one, then a `User` class instance is populated and `page.db.UserGet` is not null, meaning the email is taken. If it is still null, then no user with that email was found and the email is available.

What am I doing wrong here?

I was following this tutorial (http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20abe2/how-to-check-user-name-or-email-availability-using-Asp-Net)

Comment: you can't pass `alert` as a callback reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax won't work, you can't use `alert` as the callback function. `alert` needs to be wrapped in a proper function or it will fire immediately

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/isEmailAvailable",
        data: '{email: "' + inputemail + '" }', 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(serverResponse) {
              alert("available"); 
              /* do something with serverResponse */
        },
        failure: function() { alert("available"); }
    });
```

**[$.ajax API Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

Comment: The way to describe the issue here is that the success and failure handlers must be function references.  `alert("available")` is a function call (something that is called immediately), not a function reference that can be called later.   `function () {alert("available");}` is a function reference.